# I am getting an error in clustering with the KPrototyping clustering agorithm for clustering categroical and numerical data both

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, numeric, categorical-data

So I am using KProtoypes clustering algorithm to cluster through the mixed variables that include categorical as well as the numerical columns. 
And I am getting an error:

> '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

And also all the features have consistent data types.
I have shared a code snippet I used to run along with the screenshot of the data. 
I just want to cluster this type of data, any suggestion for clustering would be accepted.

Also, my data is as follows:
[image: excel view of the data]

And The information about the data is as follows : [image: Info of the data]

And this is the code i wrote for the k_prototype algorithm :

> kp = KPrototypes(n_clusters=3, init='random', verbose=True)
>   kp.fit(X_dummy,categorical=[7,8,9,10,11,12,13])

*Also, Do check the categorical list that I have passed in kp.fit*

Answer (score 0):

Column L in your table contains strings and numbers (`0`).

That is probably causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

This message suggests, that you try to compare a string object `(str)` with an integer `(int)`. You need to clean the data before applying an algorithm. 
Garbage In is Garbage Out.